# How to surpass Bing Map 25 waypoint limit?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, bing-maps

I am using Bing Map API with Dynamic CRM 2013 Online. My custom javascript gets all the records from the entity (currently 50 for testing) and create a route from them and show pushpins on the Bing Map (being rendered in an HTML web resource).
The issue is that Bing Map can show only 25 waypoints at a time. Is there a way to bypass this limit of 25 waypoints in Bing Map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the routing REST service and make multiple calls to the service, then merge the responses together. I created a module for Bing Maps that does that here: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Route%20Service%20Helper

Comment: thanks!! for your comment. I have checked your module already. But the problem is that I have written an algorithm which takes records from CRM then its shows an optimal route on bing map. for that i need all points at once .

Comment: You would use this module to calculate the driving time/distances then you can pass the info through the travelling salesmen algorithm. That said you will likely want to do the optimization calculation server side for better performance. You should be able to reuse a lot of this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh699893(v=VS.110).aspx